# Use a ubuntu laptop as a WiFi reciver for my windows desktop

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, wireless-networking, laptop

My laptop runs Ubuntu 15.04 on a Live USB because the hard drive died. Desktop PC doesn't have WiFi and runs Windows 8. I'd like to play some CS:GO on my desktop PC.

Is it possible to just use the laptop as a WiFi adapter for my desktop and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very possible, but the most usual setup would be to have a wired connection and share via the wifi, as a hotspot, all you have to do is click the wifi logo, edit connection, and you'll see the sharing settings.
But connecting to pc via cable you will have to use either a crossover cable or a switch/router between them.
If it's a permanent solution, look into installing dd-wrt or freNAS on the laptop, transforming it in a router, you'll get much more use out of it, like firewall, caching...